# Volatile for immutable object

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

I have a variable

```java
private volatile MultiMap myMap;

public void doProcessing {
    
     myMap = getValueFromMainThread()
     myForkJoinPool.submit(() -> readWithinMultipleThreads())


}

private void readWithinMultipleThreads() {
   readSomethingFrom(myMap.get)
}
```

I assume this might be enough and do not need myMap to be threadsafe as I read in the child thread and do not modify the state. I am also not sure if I would need volatile at all

Answer (score 1):

The `volatile` might be necesarry when you update the variable `myMap` while other threads read from it.

If you are just reading from the map you dont need a threadsafe map implementation.

[What is the volatile keyword useful for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/what-is-the-volatile-keyword-useful-for)